# Why is use of calcium carbide as an artificial fruit ripening agent banned?

Tags: safety, food-chemistry

Fruits like mangoes can be ripened using agents like ethylene, acetylene or calcium carbide. Of these, the latter is dangerous and is banned in most countries. Wikipedia says it is because calcium carbide has traces of arsenic and phosphorus. Is there any other reason?

Will it still be unsafe if pure calcium carbide is used?

Comment: I have merged your two questions into one. I normally wouldn't do that, but in this case they seem too related to keep them apart and the current answer partly already addresses your second concern.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I was under the impression double questions were not allowed.

Comment: If they are that closely related, I believe it's okay, and even better to ask them together. You are addressing the same people who are answering any way, and the whole process is not too broad to be considered together. When they are conceptually more loosely related, it's preferable to keep them separated. That's why I said I normally wouldn't do this, so your impression is right, this is an exception.

Comment: *Presumably*  $\ce{CaC2}$ is only used to produce acetylene anyway by reacting with water.  I suspect this refers to atmospheric water which isn't well-controlled so could lead to a build-up of acetylene.  If the  $\ce{CaC2}$ is used in an acetylene generator that presumably counts as using acetylene not  $\ce{CaC2}$.

Comment: My guess is that pure CaC2 is costlier to synthesize and people would use the industrial grade version which contains harmful chemicals. Thus it is banned, not due to chemical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calcium carbide is typically used by traders who can't afford a proper infrastructure for fruit ripening (sealed storage locations and gas generators). Carbide stones are put in permeable packets (typically paper bags) and hanged above the fruit boxes, where they absorb water from the air to produce acetylene gas.

This leads to two issues:

- the concentration of acetylene is uncontrolled, and given enough moisture can reach explosive levels
- permeable bags release fine particles of reaction byproducts which land on the fruits

Of course, pure calcium carbide would be safe, at least from the nutrition perspective. You'd still have the risk of explosion though, and because carbide cannot be used safely for fruit ripening, nobody is producing it in food grade in the first place.

Comment: Calcium carbide is in no way safe for consumption - it reacts with water to produce a gas and an alkali.

Comment: Why does acetylene explode? @gsurfer04. I guess the other product of hydrolysis is Calcium Hydroxide. Is that bad for fruits?

Comment: @Ashwin (1) acetylene is a combustible gas which, like most such gases is explosive when mixed with air. As for (2), pure byproducts would be mostly harmless in small concentration (though CaO may still damage the fruit skin in some cases). But nobody bothers to produce pure carbide, so you're likely to get some arsenic along with CaO.

Comment: Again, chances of poisoning would be slim to none if everyone washed their fruits properly, but food is supposed to be safe in all cases. It's like keeping rat poison next to your salt dispenser: it doesn't make your salt poisonous, but is very unsafe nevertheless.

Comment: Nice analogy to make me understand.

Answer (score 11):

According to Anwar *et al.* the use of $\ce{CaC2}$ is discouraged due to

> dangers of explosion and carryover of toxic materials like arsenic and phosphorus to consumers, thus making the healthy fruit poisonous. Since no technical knowledge is considered necessary for its anomalous use, higher quantity of calcium carbide needed to ripen immature fruit, makes them 
>   tasteless.

For references and more information, see: Anwar, R., A.U. Malik, M. Amin, A. Jabbar and B.A. Saleem, *Int. J. Agri. Biol.* **2008,** *10*, 35–41. Available at [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228508694_Packaging_material_and_ripening_methods_affect_mango_fruit_quality).

Comment: I have no idea what the second sentence of the quote is supposed to mean!

Comment: It is directly from the linked paper and seems to be badly written. This is what I understood. Since Calcium Carbide can be used by anyone, there is a chance that people will use a higher quantity as it should hasten ripening. This leads to the fruit becoming tasteless, in addition to it being poisoned.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit poorly formatted, but I interpreted it as Ashwin did.  People with little to no understanding on the effects of the chemical use large quantities of it, and end up spoiling the taste.