# Calcium carbide as a ripening agent

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Calcium Carbide is banned as a ripening agent in many countries because it contains traces of arsenic and phosphorus. Will it still be unsafe if pure Calcium Carbide is used?

Comment: Hello there! You've asked a *very* similar question a while back https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74623/artificial-ripening-of-fruits. Since what you're asking here also fits well in your previous question, you'd be well advised to to insert your query *"Will it still be unsafe if pure Calcium Carbide is used?"* in your previous post. As it stands, *this* particular post will be closed as a "duplicate" of your previous one. We look forward to your future contributions on Chem.SE. Cheers!